# Best approach to show default image

Tags: c#, jquery, image

Looking for information - I am creating a catolog website that includes a list of products. Each product has an image stored stored on the hard drive on the server. If the image does not exist, I want to show a default image. Whats the best way of doing this. I am using C# and considered checking on the server side if the image exists. But as some pages could have 50-60 images this would slow down the page. I use jquery on the client side. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question, as the sitation arises in many circumstances. I see several options:

1) check for image availability during rendering of the catalog and use a link to the default image for items that do not have an image,

2) check for image availability in the image controller and return the default image when not available

3) put images inline in the document using data URLs

A major factor here is the possibility of caching.

Option (1) facilitates caching of the default image, but precludes caching of the catalog page. It is better if there are many items without an image, then such items will not even generate a hit to the server Furthermore, if there's a low chance that an image would appear for an item, you could cache the index too (for a reasonably short time).

Option (2) facilitates caching of the index page, but each image will have to send a request to the server. Again, you could use aggressive caching to avoid the same requests the second time the page is rendered.

Option (3) is best if your images are small and if the catalog page is relatively static. Be sure to use caching on the server side though while generating the page to reduce the load on the filesystem/database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a web application, so you should look into doing some caching. Even though image file lookups are expensive, once your page gets hit a few times the disk lookups will no longer be necessary.

Or you could store the information about whether a product image exists in your database. Then you prepopulate the database with the information and no disk checks are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do this server-side as you suggest.  You could do it client-side (attempt to load image, and load a default image if that fails), but this is not really what client-side scripting is designed for.  You're making the user do extra HTTP requests, which is slower for the user.

An even better solution, as marcind suggests, is to pre-populate the database with default images.  So in your CMS, when you create a new item, it assigns a default image URL to itself.  You can then manually change it from there.

Comment: I don't think marcind is suggesting pre-poulating the database with default images. But rather just a flag indicating if the product has an image or not. populating each record with the name of a default image is not a good design. It uses up more space (more space translates to slower query responses) and if for some reason you need to change the name or path of the default image in the future it would becomes a nighmare.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, but I don't quite agree with the logic.  Returning a one-bit flag vs. a 30bit URL is not really going to affect speed much, though it will increase the size of your database slightly (more noticable with massive databases).  I do agree that it's cleaner when/if you want to change the default image URL, but this is not at all hard to do: update 'table' set 'imageURL' = replace(imageURL,'defaultURL','newDefaultURL');

Comment: Jeff, size of the database increases Disk I/O and thus reduces performance (considering that disk I/O is probably responsible for "slow" most times systems. Then you also have redundant data in your table. So from a database design perspective a bad idea as well. I guess my suggestions were aimed towards how best to do it and not "it's possible in these 10 ways". What you're suggesting is "do-able" sure. But I wouldn't :)

Answer (score 0):

How does your jQuery code know the name of the image?

Seeing that your image files are physical files on the server and are accessible from a browser, I'd probably leave that part as is since that implies you don't have to serve the images yourself and IIS can handle that for you as a static file.

So your jQuery code obviously know the name of the image for each product. I assume this name is given to it by some server side process, so that process needs to give it either the name of the image for the product or the default image.

Some part of your code has to go through the process of figuring out if an image exists for the product and react accordingly. If you're using a database for your products that you could have a field in product table that indicates if the product has an image or not.